# remove line if word start in line

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, json

we are trying to the delete the line that started with "content" word but without success

"content" word actually can start in the begging of file or after spaces or TAB

what is wrong in the sed syntax ?

```
 sed  "/^[ \t]*"content"\b/Id" file.txt

  "version" : 9,
  "Config" : {
    "cluster_name" : "HDP",
    "stack_id" : "HDP"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "content" : "\n#!/bin/bash\n\n# Set KAFKA specific environment variables here.\n\n# 
  "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
.
.
```

expected output from file.txt

```
  "version" : 9,
  "Config" : {
    "cluster_name" : "HDP",
    "stack_id" : "HDP"
  },
  "properties" : {
  "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `sed` if all you're doing is filtering lines based on patterns. That's what `grep` is for:

```
grep -iv '^[[:space:]]*"content"' < file.txt
```

`grep -i`, as opposed to that `I` address flag is standard.

Or if that's a proper JSON file, you can use a JSON parsing utility like `jq` to delete that that key:

```
jq 'del(.properties.content)' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues here:

1. the double quotes in the pattern won't be matched because you used double quotes to enclose the expression
2. `"` is a non-word character, so there will not be a word *boundary* after it

So

```
sed  '/^[ \t]*"content"/Id' file.txt
```

or (if you must use double quotes around the expression)

```
sed  "/^[ \t]*\"content\"/Id" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

we can just do by using below command

```
sed -e  '/^\s*"content"/d'  file.txt
```

output

```
"version" : 9,
  "Config" : {
    "cluster_name" : "HDP",
    "stack_id" : "HDP"
  },
  "properties" : {
  "kafka_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
.
.
```

Comment: Won’t the second expression delete a line that has “content” *anywhere* in it? That’s not what the requirement is (beginning of line or after spaces or tab).

Comment: @JeffSchaller Command corrected Can you please look into it and let me know for any changes

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*"content"/d' is needed. What you've come up with will remove more than needed lines. firstly the content keyword needs to be enrobed in double quotes which is not the case here. then you also remove lines which have a space followed by the keyword anywhere in the line.